# How do I set the Phusion Passenger option for passenger_response_buffer_high_watermark?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, zip, streaming, passenger

I have nginx installed with phusion passenger v 6.0.12 hosting a rails 6 app.

There is a setting ([passenger_response_buffer_high_watermark](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/references/config_reference/nginx/#passenger_response_buffer_high_watermark)) that essentially allows you to turn off the default buffering provided by phusion passenger by assigning a very low value.  However, when attempting to set this in my server block I get the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "passenger_response_buffer_high_watermark" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/windows-logic:22
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Any idea on how to set this option in my nginx server or even a specific location block to allow configuring this option?

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name app.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    root /var/www/app-example-com/public;

    passenger_response_buffer_high_watermark 64;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.1/bin/ruby;
    passenger_app_env staging;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do reproduce if I put that directive in `server` block, but I do not if I put in `nginx.conf`, `http` block:

```
http {
  ...  
  passenger_min_instances 5;
  passenger_max_pool_size 10;  
  passenger_response_buffer_high_watermark 64;
  ...
}
```

It is strange though because in the [docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/references/config_reference/nginx/#passenger_response_buffer_high_watermark), at Context says: `http, server, location, if` and from my understanding it should work inside `server` too.